# I just converted my full disk of GUID to MBR, how to recover the data?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I had a full 1.5 TB disk with a GUID partition table, I converted it to MBR successfully with diskpart.exe because it was having problems. How do I get my data back?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this software, it requires a lot or reading before use, its not exactly user friendly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk

Authors page here
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk